# How to simulate mod_wsgi prefix in django tests?

Tags: django, testing, mod-wsgi

I'm using mod_wsgi with a url prefix. my setup is:

```
Alias /prefix /path_to_wsgi_file/file.wsgi
<Directory /path_to_wsgi_file>
  Options ExecCGI
  SetHandler wsgi-script
  ...
</Directory>
```

I would like my django tests to simulate this situation so I could avoid differences between the testing and real env. That means I want request.get_full_path() to contain the /prefix

Any way to do that?

**EDIT:** after going through the source to understand what FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME does, looks like it's used when wsgi.py calls set_script_prefix() of urlresolvers.
My problem is that this isn't called when I run "manage.py test".
I guess I could call this method myself in the test.
Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you'll have the `SCRIPT_NAME` properly configured on the Web server and let `reverse` handle everything for you. If you want to configure a particular prefix to be applied, you can configure [`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/?from=olddocs#forcing-the-url-prefix-to-a-particular-value), which will override any particular `SCRIPT_NAME` that may be configured or not.

This will allow you to reverse and serve URLs on a given `/prefix`.